# Multiple Fields in Ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code that takes the field "text1" and passes it to a php page that processes it.  Despite the fact that I am aware of what to do on the php page for multiple text fields, I can't figure out this part below because I'm not that great at ajax...

So my question is, how do I convert the following code to make it work for 3 text fields instead of just one?  (example, "text1, text2, text3")

Here is the code...

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            var ths = this;
            var str = $(ths).siblings("#text1").val();

        $.post("saveData.php", {t:str}, function(value){
                $(ths).parent("#c").fadeOut("fast");
                $(ths).parent("#c").siblings("#cn").html(value);
        });
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass multiple data in [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), like:

```
....
var str = $(ths).siblings("#text1").val(),
   str1 = $("#text2").val(),
   str2 = $("#text3").val();
$.post("saveData.php", {t:str, t2 : str1, t3 : str2}, function(value){
  ...
```

Comment: okay, now that was so simple I feel dumber as to have asked that question.  Gonna go stick my face in a tub of acid now.  Jeesh!

Comment: Oh and THANKS.  Appreciated much!